# Create New Column If Statement Based on Duplicate Rows in R

Tags: sql, r

I want to create a new column based on whether or not it is a duplicate row.  I have my data ordered by user # then date.  I want the new column to check to see if the value in the first column is equal to the row before, then do the same for the date.

For example I have the first two columns of data and want to create a boolean array in the 3rd column whether or not it was a new user on a new day:

```
User#   Date     Unique   
1       1/1/17    1 
1       1/1/17    0
1       1/2/17    1
2       1/1/17    1
3       1/1/17    1
3       1/2/17    1
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a typo in the sample data set as the last row is unique per the given criteria

```
df1$Unique <- c(1, diff(df1$User) != 0 | diff(df1$Date) != 0)

  User       Date Unique
1    1 2017-01-01      1
2    1 2017-01-01      0
3    1 2017-01-02      1
4    2 2017-01-01      1
5    3 2017-01-01      1
6    3 2017-01-02      1
```

**update**

If the users are stored as factors then the following will work

```
User <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
User <- letters[User]
Date <- c("1/1/17", "1/1/17", "1/4/17", "1/1/17", "1/1/17", "1/2/17")
df1 <- data.frame(User, Date)
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%y")

df1$Unique <- c(1, diff(as.numeric(df1$User)) != 0 | diff(df1$Date) > 1)

  User       Date Unique
1    a 2017-01-01      1
2    a 2017-01-01      0
3    a 2017-01-04      1
4    b 2017-01-01      1
5    c 2017-01-01      1
6    c 2017-01-02      0
```

Comment: Is there a way you would adapt the code above if the user ID has a mix of letters and numbers?  And adapt to be "unique" if the date difference is less than 2 days?   I applied your method to my data and got a "1" for the first row then NA the rest of the way down.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PMo updated answer to include Users that are stored as text and date range

Answer (score 0):

This may give you what you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)

User <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3)
Date <- c("1/1/17","1/1/17","1/2/17","1/1/17","1/1/17","1/2/17")

df <- data.frame(User,Date,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df %>%
       group_by(User, Date) %>%
       mutate(Unique = if_else(duplicated(Date) == FALSE, 1, 0))
```

Comment: perfect thank you, and yes i changed the typo up top, you were correct